# Mahalanobis distance computation in Python

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, linear-algebra, mahalanobis

When computing the Mahalanobis distance on the following (poorly correlated) dataframe, I get weird distance values. Here is the python code:

#### dataframe

```
data = { 'Price': [100000, 800000, 650000, 700000, 
               860000, 730000, 400000, 870000, 
               780000, 400000], 
     'Distance': [16000, 60000, 300000, 10000, 
                  252000, 350000, 260000, 510000, 
                  2000, 5000], 
     'Emission': [300, 400, 1230, 300, 400, 104, 
                  632, 221, 142, 267], 
     'Performance': [60, 88, 90, 87, 83, 81, 72,  
                     91, 90, 93], 
     'Mileage': [76, 89, 89, 57, 79, 84, 78, 99,  
                 97, 99] 
       }
```

#### import libraries

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd  
import scipy as stats
```

#### create dataset

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Price', 'Distance', 
                            'Emission','Performance', 
                            'Mileage'])
```

#### compute the correlation matrix

```
df.corr(numeric_only=True)
```

#### the Mahalanobis distance function

```
def calculateMahalanobis(y=None, data=None, cov=None): 

    y_mu = y - np.mean(data) 
    if not cov: 
        cov = np.cov(data.values.T) 
    inv_covmat = np.linalg.inv(cov) 
    left = np.dot(y_mu, inv_covmat) 
    mahal = np.dot(left, y_mu.T) 
    return mahal.diagonal()
```

#### create new column in dataframe that contains Mahalanobis distance for each row

```
df['MahalanobisDistance'] = calculateMahalanobis(y=df, data=df[['Price', 'Distance', 'Emission','Performance', 'Mileage']])
```

#### display the dataframe

```
print(df)
```

[image]

All the distances in the last column are **equal and so large**! Why? I carefully checked the function and it seems correct. On the contrary the first 10, as an example, are expected to be the following (from a reliable source):

[image]

Comment: I ran your code exactly copied from your post, and the results match your expected output. Maybe you have some other code that didn't make it into this post that's affecting the computation?

Comment: Also, the wrong `MahalanobisDistance` column doesn't have exactly the same values (note the 4-7th significant digits). This might be a clue to find the extra code that's different from your post.

Comment: Never post picture of data, this is counter productive and waste resources for less efficiency.